# Suddenly access denied cUrl in PHP

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-403

I used the following function to get access to an API (live working example)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.halteverbotszonen.com/api/numbers');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

Since a few  days (can't tell exactly when) it gives me a 403 error when executing the curl call. Accessing `https://www.halteverbotszonen.com/api/numbers` directly is possible. I have not changed anything on any of the two servers, what could possibly cause this and where could I see that (any logs for this?)

I have a second api where the same happens (accessible directly works, but not via curl call).
It's the same hoster, could they have changed something that does not allow incoming curl calls?

Any hint appreciated

Comment: Accessing `https://www.halteverbotszonen.com/api/numbers` directly on my computer, I've first get an SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN error, then `Access denied` as reponse.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. You should ask the owner of the API first, for me it just looks like as they shut down access to their API, simple as that.

Comment: I am the owner of the API, it's my clients website which I monitor locally. I didn't change a thing so I was wondering what could cause that... Not really sure what would be zhe right topic though...

Comment: Maybe you can check why the request made from my post was denied then? It could help find the culprit. Also, maybe add to your question the fact that's your API.

Comment: That would be the best I guess, but not sure where to start as https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=halteverbotszonen.com shows everything is fine...

Comment: I wasn't speaking about SSL, but instead why your API return "Access denied" when I try to access it (same result today)

Answer (score 0):

```
- Maybe due to https/http ?
- Maybe a different conf inside your apache/php ?
- Maybe the distant server banned your IP
```

:o

In most of cases, when something works and PAF another day didn't work anymore, it's a software update problem (like conf file) or network problem (like IP) or distant problem (like the server). I guess :D